# How to add JSON field to Gatsby sourceNode?

Tags: javascript, json, graphql, gatsby

In my API, I have `layout` prop with dynamic schema, so I add this to `sourceNode` as stringified JSON:

```
  for (const { path } of nodesList) {
    /* ... */

    const node = {
      id: createNodeId(`cms-${cmsNode.id}`),
      /* this prop */
      layout: JSON.stringify(layout),
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        content: JSON.stringify(cmsNode),
        type: 'CmsNode',
      },
    }
    node.internal.contentDigest = createContentDigest(node)
    createNode(node)
  }
```

How to customize this field to parse JSON on query level, instead of `JSON.parse` in page component?

Comment: use graphql custom json type (docs) ... don't stringify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have to add custom type:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type CmsNode implements Node @dontInfer {
      id: ID!
      parent: Node
      children: [Node!]!
      ...
      layout: JSON
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

and don't stringify this prop during `createNode`.